# Renaming multiple files from subdirectories using CMD for EX: 123_abc.pdf file to 123_abc_DOC.pdf

Tags: cmd

I tried with the below command but is cuts some part of file n replace the _TEST.pdf with it

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.pdf) DO REN "%f" *_TEST.pdf
```

EX:
Orgininal file name is `TEST_123.pdf`

Renamed file name is `TEST_TEST.pdf`

Expected result is `TEST_123_TEST.pdf`

Comment: The behaviour you encountered is perfectly described here: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards? (SuperUser)](https://superuser.com/a/475875)

Answer (score 1):

use modifiers (see `for/?`):

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.pdf) DO REN "%~ff" "%~nf_TEST%~xf"
```

this is command line syntax. To use it in a batch file, double each `%`:

```
FOR /R %%f IN (*.pdf) DO REN "%%~ff" "%%~nf_TEST%%~xf"
```